# Compiling FFMPEG error "not found using pkg-config"

Tags: ffmpeg, pkg-config

I used the follow command to configure FFMPEG:

```
./configure  --enable-pthreads --enable-pic --enable-shared --enable-rpath --arch=amd64 --enable-demuxer=dash --enable-libxml2 --enable-libvvdec --enable-libvvenc --disable-x86asm
```

And I have that error:

```
ERROR: libvvdec >= 1.6.0 not found using pkg-config
```

But the *libvvdec* library is installed in 1.6.1 version. If I use `pkg-config libvvdec --modversion` it show that:

```
1.6.1
```

So, why might this error be occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Your configure line should look like this:
`PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/path/to/pkgconfig:/alt_path/to/pkgconfig" ./configure ...`